# Writing to the ApplicationData folder with NLog Configuration API

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a desktop application application that is bundled with a WCF service. Both were built using .NET 4.7.2. The application and the service share an install directory with each other, and they both use NLog 4.5.8 for logging. The only difference in the way they each use NLog is that the application uses an NLog.config file to set up its logging properties while the service uses the [NLog Configuration API](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API).

Note that the reason I'm using the NLog Configuration API for the service is because the service seemingly refuses to use the NLog.config file that the application uses even though it sits in the same directory as the two of them. It simply won't log unless I configure it using the NLog Configuration API.

Anyway, everything seems to be working fine with the NLog Configuration API; however, I can't get it to target the ApplicationData folder for log file storage as I can when using the NLog.config file.

In the NLog.config file, the ApplicationData folder can be targeted as follows:

```
<target xsi:type="File"
        name="infoLogFile"
        layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${callsite}|${logger:shortName=true}: ${message}"
        fileName="${specialfolder:ApplicationData}\Program\file.log"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName="${specialfolder:ApplicationData}\Program\file_${shortdate}.{##}.log"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="30"
/>
```

I've set up my FileTarget using the NLog Configuration API as follows:

```
var infoFileTarget = new FileTarget("infoFileTarget")
{
    Layout = @"${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${callsite}|${logger:shortName=true}: ${message}",
    FileName = "${specialfolder:ApplicationData}/Program/file.log",
    KeepFileOpen = false,
    ArchiveFileName = "${specialfolder:ApplicationData}/Program/file_${shortdate}.{##}.log",
    ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Sequence,
    ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Day,
    MaxArchiveFiles = 30,
};
config.AddTarget(infoFileTarget);
```

Unfortunately this does not work.

However, setting the FileName/ArchiveFileName to both of the following does work:

```
FileName = "${basedir}/Program/file.log", // this works
```

or

```
FileName = "C:/Users/<USERNAME>/AppData/Roaming/Program/file.log, // this works
```

It would seem that targeting the ApplicationData folder should work, but I must be missing something. Does anyone with experience using NLog have any idea how I can get this to work?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more digging and it turns out that my issue is actually occurring because `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` refers to a different location when referenced by a Windows Service running under the LocalSystem account and not due to a bug in NLog. The workaround for me was to choose to log to the `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` folder as that location does not change when referenced by a Windows Service.

I used [this reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d89c3df2-59bf-4dd9-8f36-fb8594120013/the-path-is-not-valid-check-the-directory-for-the-database-in-sqlce?forum=csharpgeneral) to come up with my solution.

Comment: I found I had to use CommonApplicationData also and this is with a Windows Application (not a service)

Answer (score 2):

If you think `${specialfolder:ApplicationData}` (or another layout) isn't working, you could log this to file. e.g.

```
<target xsi:type="File"
        name="infoLogFile"
        layout="${longdate}|my application data folder: ${specialfolder:ApplicationData}"
        fileName="c:\temp\test.log"

/>
```

I think the username in `C:/Users/<USERNAME>/AppData/Roaming/Program/file.log` could be unexpected.

Side note:

`${specialfolder}` is supported in full .NET framework and .NET Standard 2, not .NET standard 1. NLog is using [`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netcore-2.1#System_Environment_GetFolderPath_System_Environment_SpecialFolder_) to retrieve the folder.

Comment: Thanks, Julian. Your answer led me to discover that the ApplicationData folder refers to a different location when referenced by a Windows Service running under the LocalSystem account. Switching my logging location to CommonApplicationData, whose location does not change when referenced by a Windows Service running under the LocalSystem account, was a viable workaround for me.

Answer (score 0):

[This nlog bug](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1365) suggests that `specialfolder` doesn't work on dot net core.

The work around seems to be:

```
<variable name="logFolder"
 value="${environment:variable=APPDATA:whenEmpty=${environment:variable=HOME}}/Log" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in .NET 4.7.2

Comment: `${specialFolder}` isn't supported in .NET Standard 1, but it is in the Full framework and .NET Standard 2.